# Creating multiple sheets of excel from c# using streamwriter

Tags: c#, excel, streamwriter

I'm using the streamwriter to create an excel file. but the problem is that I didn't find a way to create multiple sheets and specify their names from c#. Also I wanted to draw a chart on excel using streamwriter. So does anybody have an idea how to do both things using streamwriter and not excel instance??
My code is like this:

```
String sPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\Synthese.xls";
FileStream oFile = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(oFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
oWriter.WriteLine("<table border='1' border-color='#ffffff' style=font-weight:bold;><tr>");
...
oWriter.Close();
oFile.Close();
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(sPath);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myFile.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myFile.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(myFile.FullName);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are writing in the XML format. So you will need to open an Excel file as XML and look at the formatting they use to specify new sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write pseudo-HTML to a xls file and hope it works... I'd be surprised if Excel even opens it.

You are better off using a proper tool for the job.

I suggest looking at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which allows you to create excel documents in C# with all the features you are describing.

Example [lifted from the codeplex site](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContentSheetExample):

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample6.xlsx");

ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

//Add the Content sheet
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
ws.View.ShowGridLines = false;

//Headers
ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Name";
ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Size";
ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Created";
ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Last modified";
ws.Cells["B1:E1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

---

Additionally it is advisable to use `using` statements when using `IDisposable` classes such as `FileStream`:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    // ... stuff using stream in here
}
```

Comment: Actually it's opening but it's complicated. Thank you for your advice, I will try it.